# Can I give an nhibernate session factory a list of mappings to load?

Tags: nhibernate

Right now, the session factory just finds all .hbm.xml files embedded in the current assembly it seems. I now have a situation where I only want the session factory to load the list of mappings that I specify. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Configuration.AddResources(IEnumerable<string> paths, Assembly assembly)` and specify a desired list of mappings, do your own filtering if you insist having the mappings embedded in the same assembly. Otherwise I would recommend Sergio's answer.

You can use a static method on Configuration class to return a list of available mappings in an assembly, then you can remove the ones you don't want:

```
var mappings = Configuration.GetAllHbmXmlResourceNames(assembly);
// TODO: filter mappings
cfg.AddResources(mappingsFiltered, assembly);
```

Comment: actually the Configuration.AddAssembly method gets a list of resources calling Configuration.GetAllHbmXmlResourceNames, then iterates over the items and calls AddResource for each and one of them.

Comment: aha, so that's why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: Just a bit of background.. I have one database with hundreds of tables in it that are shared by a whole bunch of different frontends. Some tables are needed by multiple frontends so I'm trying to keep the business logic all in one place, but at the same time I want to make sure these frontends are allowed to access only the tables they need and no more.

Comment: I think you need a way to configure the list of assemblies you want to load, maybe separate them by paths (namespaces), use some sort of configuration file or convetion method. You can run into errors when building NHibernate configuration if you don't include related mappings

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the configuration of NHibernate, you specify the assembly where you have embedded your mappings right? What I would suggest is change that configuration dynamically based on your needs.

Another way to do it at run-time would be using the NHibernate.cfg.Configuration.CreateMappings method to create the mappings dynamically. This would require you to create the mappings either on the fly (you can read from a DB or files or something). I personally haven't done this way but I think you could give it a try to solve your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS. I think this is possible to work because you would create first the NHibernate configuration Object, then create/add the mappings and then you can create the Session Factory.

Comment: I could make assemblies for each mapping file situation but I don't want to do that. I guess I'll look at the createmappings method. Btw, if I do use create mappings, how do I tell it not to load all the mappings floating around in the assembly?

Comment: Well, as I said before, I haven't done that before, so don't assume that what I'm saying in 100% correct, but I think that if you don't specify the Mappings Assembly line in the configuration there won't be any mappings loaded to your SessionFactory and therefore just the mappings you add using CreateMappings method would be available to persist objects.

Comment: yeah, Vasile explained it was the addassembly method that actually loaded all the mappings for me